# Access Denied status getting custom service's characteristics with GetCharacteristicsAsync

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, .net-standard

I'm attempting to get the characteristics of a custom BLE service. I have a NETStandard class library, making use of NETCore build 17134 for Bluetooth communication. This library is then used in a WPF application (.NET Framework 4.7.1.) I'm able to connect to my BLE peripheral, as well as read the generic service that includes Hardware Revision, etc. However, when it then goes to get the characteristics of my custom service, the status reads AccessDenied and the array of characteristics is empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The same code works when it's purely UWP. However, I have no way to set Bluetooth permissions in the desktop app as I can in UWP. I've attempted running as administrator and performing the workaround using an AppID/registry entry. It didn't seem to work, but perhaps I simply did something wrong.

Is this a known issue? I've read there's been some regression since the original Creator's Update (15xxx) but the threads all seem about a year old.

```
    protected async override Task<IList<ICharacteristic>> GetCharacteristicsNativeAsync()
    {
        var accessRequestResponse = await _nativeService.RequestAccessAsync();

        // Returns Allowed
        if (accessRequestResponse != Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceAccessStatus.Allowed)
        {
            throw new Exception("Access to service " + _nativeService.Uuid.ToString() + " was disallowed w/ response: " + accessRequestResponse);
        }

        var allCharacteristics = await _nativeService.GetCharacteristicsAsync(Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
        // Status: AccessDenied
        var status = allCharacteristics.Status;

        // No error
        var err = allCharacteristics.ProtocolError;
        var nativeChars = allCharacteristics.Characteristics;
        var charList = new List<ICharacteristic>();

        foreach (var nativeChar in nativeChars)
        {
            var characteristic = new Characteristic(nativeChar, this);
            charList.Add(characteristic);
        }

        return charList;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this can be the problem: var accessRequestResponse = await _nativeService.RequestAccessAsync();. Can you try this app btframework.com/GattClient.zip Can it read your services?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Mike. Yes, the program you linked is able to read the characteristics. Did you manually perform a security handshake or something similar in your implementation?

Comment: No, it does not perform any security handsake. The only difference there is we do not use RequestAccessAsync(). So try to comment that out. Also try to change GetCharacteristicsAsync to common one GetCharacteristicsAsync() (without providing reading mode). The code that GattClient uses also works with .NET Core (tested on Windows 10 Iot) so I do not thingk that this is .NET Core issue.

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but the problem remains. The characteristics status is still AccessDenied when I attempt to get them. I was using the RequestAccessAsync method to check if my service was perhaps unavailable, but it always returned Success. So the program can see the service, but it's denied access to getting its characteristics. Since your software worked, and we have a number of other apps using this same BLE service, it's safe to say the peripheral itself isn't denying access. I'm stumped.

Comment: Is your device paired?

Comment: Mike, I was able to resolve the issue! Essentially, the Service was being referenced by another (observable) object and, thus -- I believe, anyway -- direct access was being denied. Data is now streaming from my peripheral. Thank you for your help and suggestions!

Comment: Removing the call to RequestAccessAsync() prior to calling GetCharacteristicsAsync fixed this error for me.

Comment: Mr. Bungle's fix fixed it for me as well. 
It works in the BluetoothLE UWP sample UI app, but failed in a .NET console app.

Comment: Might be a problem of using Async from Sync. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-blocking-hack